# Extract 2 lists out of csv file in python

Tags: python, list, csv, rows

How can I extract 2 columns in two python lists out of csv file.
I tried everything but I always get errors.
I just succeed making rows :

```
import csv 
with open('test-data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: This is simply the sample code of the CSV manual?

Comment: I took the code from here : https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html

Comment: I get this type of results : [974] ['Stoob', '59']
[975] ['Hochfilzen', '59']
[976] ['Henndorf', '59']
[977] ['Pischeldorf', '59']
[978] ['Vitis', '59'] I wish i can extract the name of the town for example in a python list [Henndorf, Pischeldorf, Vitis...]... and another list with [59, 59, 58,...] etc... i have more than 1000 datas